# FB app is not integrated correctly in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I am following this tutorial:
[Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) and I have run the samples correctly.

I now want to add the mobile adds characteristic and I follow this tutorial:
[FB mobile install ads](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/)

In the step1 it says:

```
Set up your app to measure mobile app install ads
```

Step by step, and I comment what I have done already:

```
1.You need to integrate Facebook's latest SDK -->DONE with the tutorial getting started
2.For iOS 3.0 or greater, add the following to your UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive selector:
[FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID];-->DONE

I have added:
[FBSettings publishInstall:@"220............"]; in my appdelegate.m and imported the <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

and then comes the problem:

```
3. You can confirm that your app is correctly configured in the App Dashboard, or go directly there at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID. You should see a field in the "Summary" section labeled "Last Mobile Install Reported," with a time stamp for the last time your app reported an install.
```

This is what I suppose to see:
[image: suppose to see]

and this is what I see:

[image]

How am I supposed to know that I have setup this correctly and my fb mobile install ads will play normally?

EDIT:

I have added both the URLScheme:

[image: URL Scheme]

and the linker flag:

[image: Other Linker flag]

And the native ios info:

[image: native ios info]

Still the problem remains:( I do not see that my app is being installed from my phone..

This doesn't work only if I set the campaign and the ad right? Because I~ haven't created the ad yet, i just want to make sure that I will pay FB and my ad is going take users to my app.

Comment: Are you add a some app for this ? Example, iOS app or Android app

Comment: @CReaTuS yes i have filled the native ios segment with the bundle id and the appstore id..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, you still haven't set everything up correctly, so I'm just going to walk you through the process quickly.

The first you need to do is go to your project, and select your app's target >> Build Settings and search for "Other Linker Flags". There you will add" -lsqlite3.0", like the picture shows below.[image]

Next, you need to navigate back to the Summary tab, and scroll down to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", and add the Social, Accounts, and AdSupport framework. Also, change them from required to optional for older devices. Also add the FacebookSDK framework. You should have something like this:[image]

Lastly, you need to do what seems to be giving you the hardest time. Navigate to your .plist file in your project navigator. In there, you need to modify your plist to reflect something like this:[image]

Be sure that you're being VERY precise with capitalizations and such. I say that because I notice that you put "id" instead of "ID" in your question.

The last thing you have to do is simply import the FacebookSDK framework into your file when you are ready to use it.

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

One last extra tip. I always add a bundle called "FacebookSDKResources.bundle" because I find that I often times end up using it. The bundle can be found in FacebookSDK >> FacebookSDK.framework >> Resources. Add that bundle to your project the same way you added the FacebookSDK.faramework file itself, and you should be all ready to go!

Comment: Nice answer with screenshots. My answer is just not understandable texts =)

Comment: I thought your answer is sufficient. I just remember back to when I did this for the first time, and screenshots of what to do were really what it took for me to do the whole thing properly :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems, you don't have set a 'URL Scheme Suffix' in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps):

Example,

```
fb12345678901234
```

And in your app bundle:

Example,

```
FacebookAppID: 12345678901234
```

And in **URL Types** at **URL Schemes** ( Target->Info->URL Types->URL Schemes ) :

Example,

```
fb12345678901234
```

Comment: Also, make sure that you have set your "Other Linker Flags" to "-lsqlite3.0". in the Build Settings of your project.

Comment: @CReaTuS I have done this, I haven't checked the Other linker flags.

Comment: @ghostrider I am not see a 1) fb12345678901234 at 'URL Types' at 'URL Schemes' in app bundle, 2) Also add a fb12345678901234 in 'URL Scheme Suffix' at Facebook site

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to launch app on the simulator?
I've had the same problem, until I've loaded the build onto real device.